# How to change position of an OPENFILENAME dialog in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

This is my attempt using a hook function to get the dialog window handle. Both `SetWindowPos()` and `GetLastError()` return correct values, but the dialog window is unaffected and shown at position `0,0`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static UINT_PTR CALLBACK OFNHookProc (HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  using namespace std;
  switch (uiMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: {
      // SetWindowPos returns 1
      cout << SetWindowPos(hdlg, HWND_TOPMOST, 200, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE ) << endl;
      // GetLastError returns 0
      cout << GetLastError() << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW);
  ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
  ofn.lpfnHook = OFNHookProc;
  GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will condemn you to use the horrid XP legacy dialog

Comment: The return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless at the time your are calling it. It reports a meaningful value only when `SetWindowPos` fails, and only when you call it *immediately* following the failed API call. The interspersed stream operators can change the calling thread's recorded last error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `OFN_EXPLORER`, you have to move `hdlg`'s **parent window**, as the HWND passed to your callback is not the actual dialog window.  This is clearly stated in the documentation:

[OFNHookProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646931.aspx)

> hdlg [in]
>   A handle to the **child dialog box** of the Open or Save As dialog box. **Use the GetParent function to get the handle to the Open or Save As dialog box.**

Also, you should wait for the callback to receive the [`CDN_INITDONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646863.aspx) notification, instead of the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

Try this:

```
static UINT_PTR CALLBACK OFNHookProc (HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if ((uiMsg == WM_NOTIFY) &&
      (reinterpret_cast<OFNOTIFY*>(lParam)->hdr.code == CDN_INITDONE))
  {
    SetWindowPos(GetParent(hdlg), HWND_TOPMOST, 200, 200, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```